# Sending a message to a not yet started activity

Tags: android, android-activity, handler

In my application I start a Register activity from the Main Activity with a button

`startActivity( new Intent(getBaseContext(),Register.class));`

This Register activity creates records that can be viewed in a ListActivity.

If I go to the ListActivity from the Main Activity (with another button) and decide that I want to send the data of a record from the ListActivity to the Register activity in order to edit it, there are two possibilities:

1- the Register activity has never been called

2- the Register activity is opened in the background

I have two questions:

-Calling startActivity Register.class once from Main and once from ListActivity will it make two copies of Register or one?

-When I call Register activity from ListActivity and try to pass data with a handler, the handler message arrives before the activity is opened and the data do not show in the Register screen? How can I do that? Is there a way to know from the ListActivity when the view of Register is opened?

Thanks.
Charles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question has a complex answer, but shortly you can control instantiation of activities, only it has implications in flow of user interaction: see [Activities and Tasks](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#acttask), particularly [Launch modes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lmodes1).

For the second, I don't know what kind of data you're going to pass, but consider putting it in the intent with some [Intent.putExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putCharSequenceArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.CharSequence%3E%29) method (there are many for many types of data).

Comment: the kind of data is a Vector full of different data

Comment: @Charles: If they're complex objects you could add them in a bundle as serializable and then pass the bundle with the intent. But if it's a lot of data I don't know if it's an efficient way of doing it, I have no experience in this field.